# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: reactjs, go, websocket

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404, this happens when I try to connect websocket from ReactJS to Backend(Go) where I have created a handler, this is my backend code router file

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "../server"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// Router is exported and used in main.go
func Router() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/ws", server.HandleConnections) //
    router.HandleFunc("/api/block", server.GetAllBlock).Methods("GET", "OPTIONS")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/block", server.CreateBlock).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")

    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("../public")))

    return router
}
```

This is my main

```
func runWebServer() {
    r := router.Router()


    fmt.Println("Starting server on the port 8080...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", r))
}

func main() {
     go runWebServer()
}
```

This is my handleConnection function

```
func HandleConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("In handle")

    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Println("Error in ebss")
    }
    fmt.Println("No error")
    // make sure we close the connection when the function returns
    //  defer ws.Close()

    // register our new client
    nodes[ws] = true

    for {
        // Read in a new message as JSON and map it to a Message object
        var course Course
        err := ws.ReadJSON(&course)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error: %v", err)
            //  delete(nodes, ws)
            break
        }

        // Send the newly received message to the broadcast channel
        broadcast <- course
    }

}
```

This is my frontend React file where the 404 handshake error occurs

```
let endpoint = "http://localhost:8080";

    class Blockchain extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');//Here
        console.log("webs",ws)
      }
```

[This is the error shown in browser when loading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBeT2.png)

Comment: I would assume you want `ws://localhost:8080/ws` since that’s what your server has

Comment: My bad, thanks it got solved

Answer (score 0):

Here is your primary issue:

```golang
func main() {
     go runWebServer()
}
```

This runs the `runWebServer` function in a separate goroutine, which makes the main goroutine, the `main()` function call, continue past that line. Since there are no more instructions in your `main` function, the program returns. When a Go program returns, all child goroutines return. This program can't be relied upon to do anything because the `main` goroutine returns too quickly.

You should run the function in a blocking way like below or take a look at managing multiple goroutines. [This guide](https://golangbyexample.com/goroutines-golang/) may be a good place to start.

```golang
func main() {
     runWebServer()
}
```